# Loading transactional emails

Tags: magento-1.8, magento-1, email-templates, transactional-mail

I am looking for (and am so far unable to find) a way to load all the transactional email templates in Magento 1.

Is there a way to do this? I don't want to load a single one, I need to load them all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
$templates =  Mage::getResourceSingleton('core/email_template_collection');
foreach($templates as $template) {
     $singleTemplateData = $template->getData();
     // Do what you need here
}
```